# Primary and/or Logical Partitions Debian Install

Tags: linux, debian

I'm installing Debían on my laptop, I already have Win7 installed, I made a new partition with the installer, but I already have 3 primary partitions from Windows.

After making the root partition primary the remainder of the disk space (175 GBs) are "unusable", I'm not sure how to work on this, I do know that I can't have more than 4 partitions and that logical partitions are not counted there.

Can someone instruct or give me pointers on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more than 4 partitions, you'll have to convert one of the 4 primary partitions into an extended partition. Then you can put many (128? probably way more than you'll ever need) logical partitions in the extended partition.

The only problem now will be deleting the "last" primary partition (the primary partition "next to" all the free space) and then creating the extended partition over all the now free space. I don't think it would be easy to leave the data in place of that last partition, so **backing it up** to somewhere else, then restoring it to the newly created logical partitions might be required.

For Debian/linux, I'd use `gparted` to delete/create/modify partitions. I think Windows tools could do it too.

And anytime you modify partitions there's a risk of data loss, so a backup would be prudent.

Comment: Right now I'm in the partition manager of the Debian installer, apparently if I abort the installation it could mess my laptop. Currently I have partitions 1, 2, 3 from windows and 200 GBs of free storage.

Comment: If you don't have Debian installed yet, and it has not written any Debian data/partitions yet, then it would be best to create the extended partition now, and put Debian in a logical partition inside the extended partition. I don't know how the Debian installer could "mess" your laptop if it hasn't installed anything yet, but I suppose anything's possible

Comment: Well I said that because it showed a message wheb I tried to abort. I'll try what you said.

Comment: Installers often have a message like *"I'm not done installing yet! You sure you want to quit?"* if you cancel before they're done